# WINDOWS - GUI v0.12 does not launch / start

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

The new GUI (v0.12) does not start / launch, whilst GUI v0.11 used to work properly. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be caused by two things, namely (i) the path to `monero-wallet-gui.exe` contains a non-ASCII character or (ii) `monero-wallet-gui.exe` cannot properly use OpenGL rendering. The first issue will throw an error similar to this:

> "Runtime Error" - This application requested the runtime to exit in an unusual way.

The second issue, however, will not throw an error. These issues are resolved as follows:

**Issue 1:**

Ensure the GUI v0.12 binaries (the `.zip` file) are extracted to a directory whose full path does not include non-ASCII characters. Thereafter, however, it could be that you incur issue 2.

---

**Issue 2:**

Launch the GUI v0.12 via the `start-low-graphics-mode.bat` that is included. This ensures the GUI uses the Qt Quick 2D Renderer instead of relying on OpenGL. More information about the Qt Quick 2D Renderer can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuick2DRenderer/).

> Qt Quick 2D Renderer is an alternative renderer for Qt Quick 2 that uses the Raster paint engine to render the contents of the scene graph instead of OpenGL. As a result of not using OpenGL to render the scene graph, some features and optimizations are no longer available. Most Qt Quick 2 applications will run without modification though any attempts to use unsupported features will be ignored. By using the Qt Quick 2D Renderer it is now possible to run Qt Quick 2 applications on hardware and platforms that do not have OpenGL support.
>
> Qt Quick 2D Renderer is a Qt module that contains a scene graph renderer plugin.